# What happened to the Group by, Sort by, Stack by Column Header Context Menu in Windows 7 RC?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-shell

As a dev I normally group my explorer detail view by file type. This way all the config files, assemblies, executables etc are grouped and ready to be copied, just by clicking its group header to select all related files.

In beta build 7000 one could hold Ctrl and select many groups to select all the related files.

IMO since RC build 7100 just the group that first is clicked selects all related files and each subsequent click while holding Ctrl on a new group has no effect ( the related files in that group aren't selected ).

Is there any option I missed to get the behaviour back 
- that one can choose group by, sort by, stack by  from the list view column header context menu as it was in beta?
- That one could hold Ctrl and select as many groups as necessary to select related files ( for a copy operation of instance )

Comment: and how it's related to programming?

Comment: hmmm.. it's the foundation of my dev workstation, all my apps are running on windows as a platform... but you're right, it's not directly related to the programming activity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've filed a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=453069&SiteID=647) at MS Connect